# Arrays removed by removing one disk?

Tags: hard-drive, storage, ssd

I had an issue this weekend with a server at work, one of the Datastores (Raid1 2x300GB) on esxi filled up and the guest OS got suspended, we had nothing to attach an NFS to the esxi and all disk slots were busy.
So I removed one of the disks of the (Raid1 2x300GB), and broke the array on purpose, inserted an (SSD 500GB) and created another Logical disk array which I attached as a datastore on esxi, logged to esxi and copied the contents of the datastore on the single 300GB disk to this no datastore on the SSD and everything was back and running, so now i was left with 2x Raid0 on that controller and an already present Raid 10 array, the weird part is to follow.
So I intended to remove the disk left of the initial Raid1 300GB, insert the second SSD and create a new Raid1 with the 2 SSD's, the problem was when I removed this disk all the arrays and logical disks on that controller could not be seen by the server(on HP ACU or anywhere else) so I was missing the 300GB Raid0 the SSD Raid0 and my Raid10, upon inserting the 300GB disk again everything was back to normal, so i left the server as it was but with no redundancy.

I am not a big storage expert and I have tried searching this but could not seem to find anything, could someone please shed some light on what might be happening?

Many Thanks